# Instagram::BadRequest 400: 'self' keyword requires an authenticated user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, instagram

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and have been trying to create an web application using Instagram API for learning.

What I want to achieve is

1. Authentication with Instagram API
2. After the authentication, return basic information of the user

I coded along with the sample code shown in the Instagram gem on Github.
The following is what I have coded so far:

**config/initializers/instagram.rb**

```
require "instagram"

Instagram.configure do |config|
  config.client_id = "Hidden"
  config.client_secret = "for"
  config.access_token = "security reason"
end
```

**app/controllers/auth_controller.rb**

```
class AuthController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def oauth
    # Redirect to Instagram's auth page
    redirect_to Instagram.authorize_url( redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000/result/index')
  end

  def callback
    response = Instagram.get_access_token(params[:code], redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000/result/index')

    # Save access_token in Cookie
    session[:access_token] = response.access_token

    # Save user name in Cookie
    session[:username] = Instagram.client( access_token: session[:access_token]).user.username
    session[:user_id] = Instagram.client( access_token: session[:access_token]).user.id

    # Redirect to photo list page
    redirect_to controller: "result", action: "index"
  end
end
```

**app/controllers/result_controller.rb**

```
class ResultController < ApplicationController
  def index
   @client = Instagram.client(:access_token => session[:access_token])
   @recent = @client.user_recent_media
  end
end
```

When I access to localhost:3000/auth/oauth, it appears Instagram's authorization request page. After hitting "Authorize" it redirects to localhost:3000/result/index with a parameter "?code=" plus some random letters and returns an error stating

> Instagram::BadRequest in ResultController#index GET
>   https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent.json?client_id="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx":
>   400: 'self' keyword requires an authenticated user

I've been stuck on this problem for a couple of days... 
Also I want to show basic information of the user such as username, user_id, bio and profile pic of the user. How do I code in the view and controller to show such information?

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not completing the OAuth flow.

Leave off access_token in your initializer, this token is unique to the user that is logging in/authorizing your application with Instagram.

The redirect_uri should be your callback uri:

```
http://localhost:3000/auth/callback
```

This is where the temp code is exchanged for a access_token. It should not be result/index. The redirect_uri must also match the one entered for your OAuth Application on the Instagram Developer page.

http://instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/

Everything else seems about right. I recommend visiting the Instagram Ruby Gem github page, there is some great information there.

https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem